# Implementing ActionListeners to My Game Part 2

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Just a recap from my last question, I am a 15 year old new to the stackoverflow community. I am currently trying to independently develop a Rock Paper Scissors game using java. I thought working on this project would be an informing experience to help me learn java and its fundamentals. I am somewhat new with the java programming language so please do not criticize me, I am slowly learning by trial and error. For this particular project, I decided to use Eclipse as I like its user interface better than other IDEs. Anyway, I decided to implement JPanel to make the game more visual. My code is as follows copy and pasted from my eclipse project:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class prompt extends JPanel implements ActionListener {      
    public static void main(String []args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton rockButton = new JButton("ROCK");
        JButton scissorsButton = new JButton("SCISSORS");
        JButton paperButton = new JButton("PAPER");
        JFrame choicePrompt = new JFrame("Rock, Paper, Scissors Game");
        choicePrompt.add(panel);
        choicePrompt.setSize(300, 300);
        choicePrompt.setVisible(true);
        panel.add(rockButton);
        panel.add(scissorsButton);
        panel.add(paperButton);

        rockButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void rockChosen(ActionEvent r)
            {
                JLabel rock = new JLabel("You have chosen Rock!");
                panel.add(rock);
            }
        }
        scissorsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void scissorsChosen(ActionEvent s)
            {
                JLabel scissors = new JLabel("You have chosen Scissors!");
                panel.add(scissors);
            }               
        }
        paperButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void paperChosen(ActionEvent p) 
            {
                JLabel paper = new JLabel("You have chosen Paper!");
                panel.add(paper);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my ActionListeners under adding buttons to the JPanel? The way I want this program to work is that when the user clicks rock, paper, or scissors, that it displays the JLabel for their decision. All the other "shtuff" I can do myself.

Comment: Perhaps you should just have one label and change the text.

Comment: Call `panel.revalidate()` and `panel.repaint()` after adding any `JLabel` in `JPanel`.

Comment: `ActionListener` is not implemented properly in your code. where is implemented `actionPerformed()` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shouldn't even compile, and if that is the case and you're coming here for help, you need to inform us of this and post all compilation error messages, indicating which line is causing them. Recommendations:

- Don't have your class extend ActionListener.
- Give each JButton an anonymous inner class, similar to what you're doing, but one that compiles and has an actionPerformed method.
- Inside of that method, don't add a new JLabel to your GUI as that makes no sense to keep adding new components on button press. Instead have the actionPerformed call `setText(...)` on a JLabel that is already part of your GUI.
- Capitalize the first letter of your class's name to conform to Java naming standards.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement ActionLIstener properly, this interface has method actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) in it, try this (for all your listeners):

```
paperButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        JLabel paper = new JLabel("You have chosen Paper!");
        panel.add(paper);
    }
```

Comment: Swing's Layout Managers hasn't notifier that something happends in already visible Swing GUI, you have to notify the container programatically e.g. panel.revalidate() and panel.repaint(), then paper will be visible